# A-Frame : How to open a dynamically created a-link in a _blank page

Tags: aframe

this is specific to A-Frame.

I'm creating an a-link from javascript code:

```
var alinkEl = document.createElement('a-link');
alinkEl.setAttribute('href', 'http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=https://.../' + folder + fileName);
```

This does not work:

```
alinkEl.setAttribute('target', '_blank');
```

Any hint?

Comment: What do you mean exactly by "doesn't work"?

Comment: target attribute is ignored

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<a-link>`s are intended for link traversal as far as i know, not for opening new tabs. The component does not have a `target` attribute in the schema. Furthermore, the [navigation](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/aframevr/aframe/master/dist/aframe-master.js) is implemented like this:

```
navigate: function () {
  window.location = this.data.href;
}
```

So You only change the location of the given window.

---

To open a new tab I would would do the portal, and the link myself:
If You want a portal use the `portal` shader, and set the `pano` attribute:

```
<a-circle position="0 3.5 -2"
material="shader:portal;pano:_URL_TO_PORTAL_IMAGE"
></a-circle>
```

If You want it to open a new tab, make Your own component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('foo', {
  init: function() {
    this.el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
      window.open('https://ebay.com');
    })
  }
})
```

And attach it to Your portal:

```
<a-circle position="0 3.5 -2" material="shader:portal;pano:_URL_TO_PANO" 
foo></a-circle>
```

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ttug46d8/1/).

Comment: just to mention, it was about using facebook.com/sharer.php, which should be in a new tab to share, then it should close the tab and come back to the a-frame scene

Comment: @BruceLANE https://jsfiddle.net/ttug46d8/3/ the sharer seems to be working, its not closing itself after the share ?

Comment: @BruceLANE glad i could help :) feel free to mark my anwser if You don't have any further questions :)

Answer (score 2):

[It looks like](https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/primitives/a-link.html#attributes) the `<a-link>` primitive does not have the "target" attribute.

But there is an npm package that supports that. It's called *aframe-href-component* and can be found here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/aframe-href-component

Answer (score 0):

a-link **does not support** a `target` property according to https://aframe.io/docs/0.6.0/components/link.html

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have placed an `<a-cursor>` element to trigger the click event.