# Can anyone help me update this javascript to create a link to another page

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, var, aframe

I'm trying to create a link between my javascript and the image property within my HTML shown below, the link is to another page e.g. index.html.

This is in a-frame making it more difficult to find a solution.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

I know how to create a link with hrefs, basic jquery, etc.. but this won't work with my code as far as I'm aware.

```
<a-entity
        id="dialog"
        position="0 0 -3" 
        dialog-popup="

        image: img/options1.png;
        image2: img/play.png;

     ></a-entity>
```

```
  generateImage: function generateImage() {
    var _this$data5 = this.data,
        src = _this$data5.image,
        width = _this$data5.imageWidth,
        height = _this$data5.imageHeight,
        dialogBoxHeight = _this$data5.dialogBoxHeight;

    if (!src.length) {
      return null;
    }

    var image = this.imageEl || document.createElement('a-image');
    image.setAttribute('id', "".concat(this.el.getAttribute('id'), "--image"));
    image.setAttribute('src', src);
    image.setAttribute('width', width);
    image.setAttribute('height', height);
    image.setAttribute('position', {
      x: 0,
      y: dialogBoxHeight / 2,
      z: 0.5
    });
    this.hasImage = true;
    this.imageEl = image;
    return image;
  },
```

Can I somehow create a link so that when the users click the image it takes them to another page using my code?

I'm trying to target image: img/options1.png; and image2: img/play.png; specifically.

Comment: so `<a href="some other page"><img src="some image url"/></a>` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A-frame link to url with logo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506363/a-frame-link-to-url-with-logo)

Comment: No, more precisely I want to make img/options1.png; and image2: img/play.png; clickable links, is there a way I can do that.

Answer (score 0):

In a most basic case, you need to make sure you can "click" `aframe` elements:

```
<a-scene cursor="rayOrigin: mouse">
```

and then react on the `click` event within a custom component:

```
AFRAME.registerComponent("foo", {
   schema: {
       target: {},
   },
   init: function() {
       this.el.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            window.location = this.data.target;
       })
   }
})
```

and use it like this:

```
<a-entity foo="target: www.google.com"></a-entity>
```

Check it out on this [glitch](https://aframe-image-link.glitch.me/). Click the glitch button to see the sources.

---

Similar SO questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956178/a-frame-how-to-open-a-dynamically-created-a-link-in-a-blank-page) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506363/a-frame-link-to-url-with-logo)

Comment: Hi, Appreciate the help. This allows me to setup the entire a-entity as a clickable link but I should of clarified a bit more I just want the image: img/options1.png; and
image2: img/play.png; to be clickable links, is there a way I can do that.

Comment: @Zecele check out [this glitch](https://aframe-image-link.glitch.me/) . Is it like something in your mind ?

Comment: Hi, much appreciated but that doesn't seem to be what I'm after. I'll link what I have at the moment below: https://github.com/AndrewMC1994/Image-Link-Test                                                                                                     
                                                                                                            
Essentially I have a popup box with two images inside the title card and the playbutton I want once the user clicks the play button to be taken to another page. I want to target the **image2: img/play.png;**